# "cannot import name 'EVENT_TYPE_OPENED' from 'watchdog.events' "

Tags: python, flask, python-watchdog

I'm trying to make a REST api (begginer) but when i tried to initialize the server from this code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=4000)
```

---

i get this error in the prompt:

```
 from watchdog.events import EVENT_TYPE_OPENED
ImportError: cannot import name 'EVENT_TYPE_OPENED' from 'watchdog.events' 
(C:\ ********* \Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\watchdog\events.py)
```

I'm expecting something like this (Min 8:27):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMppyAPbLYk&ab_channel=TechWithTim

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try to do the following:

```
pip install --upgrade watchdog
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Gbuntu thanks. You are right, i needed to upgrade.

Comment: used watchdog-3.0.0, it is good, mine was 2.1.6 failed

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @Gbuntu's answer, the issue is likely that for some reason you're running an outdated version of watchdog.

After a bit of code archeology, I found that the support for `FileOpenedEvent` was added in version [2.3.0](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/releases/tag/v2.3.0), with the particular event constant `EVENT_TYPE_OPENED` added in [Pull Request #941](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/commit/2b09f64b8b486b94f909146385418800de8841f8#diff-d94873adedb3d85744a8e4225b200bf49e92e5c61417ea15f33b403d16920546R289).

If you prefer to set your `pip install` (or `requirements.txt`) to specific versions rather than just `--upgrade`, I would recommend either `watchdog~=2.3`, or better yet `watchdog~=3.0`.

Answer (score -2):

I was running a similar command on jupyter and got the same error... just change degug to False and no worries

Comment: Yes worries. Disabling important feature should not be a solution.